# External Trust broken

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I had a network issue on DomainA.local (switches has to be restarted), issue resolved.

logged onto DomainA fine, went to click on mapped drive (located on DomainB.local)
no access "There are no login servers available"

(Trust has been in place for 2 months with no issues)

Checked trust clicked validate, following message appears:

[image]

I clicked the "Yes reset the trust..." following message appears

[image]

I can ping by name the ad servers located on the DomainB.local and from DomainB.local to DomainA.local

I can browse(\server.DomainA.local) from DomainB.local to DomainA.local

**but I cant from DomainB.local to DomainA.local**
[image]

Ideas?

Win2008 environment,

Comment: Might something be filtering RPC or kerberos traffic now?  Double-check if a firewall got added or reconfigured around the outage time.

Comment: No firewall changes that im aware off, will look at local firewall

Comment: firewall is disabled on both DC

Comment: I know you've said you can ping the servers by name but I would suggest that you check your trust related DNS forwarders using nslookup and check the SRV records using nltest. - http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008/06/troubleshooting-cross-forest-trust.html

Comment: hey @joeqwerty , when i do a (nslookup domainb.local) I get Server: UnKnown, Address: 192.168.... Name:Domain.local Addresses: 192.168....,

Comment: When I do a (nslookup domaina.loca) I get server: dc01.domaina.local... so looks ok from this side